# OpenCV + CUDA: Different outcomes on CPU vs GPU

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, gpu, hardware-acceleration

## The Problem

I was coding an image processing application to identify unicolor circular objects in an image. I'm doing this using  **OpenCV 4.7.0** for C++. To develop the necessary functionality, I perform the following operations:

[image]

1. ***Thresholding***: Filtering out the objects by color. This is done by 3 steps:

   - Splitting the Image into `R` `G` `B` channels
   - Applying a threshold to each channel
   - Bitwise AND on the post-threshold channels
2. ***Gaussian Blurring***: Applying a Gaussian Blur filter with `ksize = 9x9` and `sigma = 1.0`
3. ***Hough Circles***: Applying the Hough Circles Transform to the blurred image. The following parameters were used (after loads of trial-and-error):

   - `dp = 1`
   - `minDist = 20`
   - `cannyThreshold = 50`
   - `votesThreshold = 30`
   - `minRadius = 1`
   - `maxRadius = 75`

After attaining satisfactory results on my CPU code, I decided to migrate it to GPU. ***Why GPU?*** Well, the application is a part of a game, which needs to run at a high frame rate

But on migrating my code to run on GPU, I noticed that the results were off from the CPU code. The GPU code returned pretty undesirable values while running on the same parameters.

***Why is this happening?***

---

## The Setup

- OpenCV 4.7.0
- CUDA v12.0
- Intel i5-10300H
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650Ti

---

## The Code

I wrote the code as two individual functions to perform the same on CPU and GPU

```
/*----------------------------------------CPU Code----------------------------------------*/

cv::Mat extractTargetsCPU(cv::Mat frame) {
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    cv::split(frame, channels);

    cv::threshold(channels[0], channels[0], 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::threshold(channels[1], channels[1], 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::threshold(channels[2], channels[2], 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    cv::bitwise_and(channels[1], channels[2], channels[1]);
    cv::bitwise_and(channels[0], channels[1], channels[0]);

    cv::Mat targets;
    cv::GaussianBlur(channels[0], channels[0], cv::Size(9, 9), 1.0f);
    cv::HoughCircles(channels[0], targets, cv::HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, 50, 30, 1, 75);

    return targets;
}
```

```
/*----------------------------------------GPU Code----------------------------------------*/

cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::Filter> gaussianFilter =  cv::cuda::createGaussianFilter(CV_8UC1, CV_8UC1, cv::Size(9, 9), 1.0f);
cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::HoughCirclesDetector> houghCircles = cv::cuda::createHoughCirclesDetector(1, 20, 50, 30, 1, 75);

cv::cuda::GpuMat extractTargetsGPU(cv::cuda::GpuMat frame) {
    std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> channels;
    cv::cuda::split(frame, channels);

    cv::cuda::Stream bThresholdStream, gThresholdStream, rThresholdStream;

    cv::cuda::threshold(channels[0], channels[0], 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY, bThresholdStream);
    cv::cuda::threshold(channels[1], channels[1], 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY, gThresholdStream);
    cv::cuda::threshold(channels[2], channels[2], 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV, rThresholdStream);

    bThresholdStream.waitForCompletion();
    gThresholdStream.waitForCompletion();
    rThresholdStream.waitForCompletion();

    cv::cuda::bitwise_and(channels[1], channels[2], channels[1]);
    cv::cuda::bitwise_and(channels[0], channels[1], channels[0]);

    gaussianFilter -> apply(channels[0], channels[0]);

    cv::cuda::GpuMat targets;
    houghCircles -> detect(channels[0], targets);

    return targets;
}
```

---

## Observations

I tested my functions on five test images and got the following outputs and sadly the GPU outputs are undesirable.

By *undesirable*, I mean that the GPU code is identifying a single circle as multiple concentric circles

To debug this, I exported the images at the Thresholding and Gaussian Blurring stages and analyzed them. Turns out that the CUDA implementation of the Gaussian Blur (`cv::cuda::createGaussianFilter`) does not perform the same function as the ordinary CPU implementation (`cv::GaussianBlur`)

To verify `HoughCircles`, I read the exported blurred image from the CPU / GPU and fed it to the Hough Transform on both CPU and GPU. The undesirable behavior was still observed on the GPU function which made me question the accuracy of `cv::cuda::createHoughCirclesDetector`

```
+---------+-------------------+----------------+
|         | Circles found by  | Gaussian Blur  |
| Image # +-------------------+ Pixel Mismatch |
|         |   CPU   |   GPU   | in GPU vs CPU  |
+---------+---------+---------+----------------+
| 1       | 1       | 3       | 324            |
| 2       | 3       | 4       | 223            |
| 3       | 3       | 4       | 213            |
| 4       | 3       | 4       | 197            |
| 5       | 1       | 2       | 179            |
+---------+---------+---------+----------------+
```

All this experimentation raised the following questions:

- Is the CUDA implementation of the standard functions accurate?
- Is this by any chance an issue of the GPU architecture rather than the issue of implementations?
- Am I missing out on something about GPU Memory / Parallelization in my implementation?
- How do I fix this / what is a possible workaround to this issue?

Comment: Did you check in which substep of your algorithm the first significant difference occurs?

Comment: Is it the same behaviour described here? https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7830

Comment: @Micka I would say that the significant error is from the `HoughCircles` step. I analyzed the `GaussianBlur` and the difference was in a 1-2 pixel contour around each circle. It is the `HoughCircles` which is messing up significantly

Comment: @Micka it pretty much is the same behaviour. Looks like the issue hasn't been resolved from OpenCV v3.1

Comment: how do the results differ? is one result clearly broken, or do they "just" differ? hough transforms aren't exact... nor is there an exact definition anywhere. there is leeway in the implementation.

Comment: For example, in cascade classifier gpu version, the last step, the non-maximum-suppression is not performed because it isnt practical to do this on gpu (and there is a function to do only this step on cpu). If only concentric circles (similar to duplicates) are the additional detections in houghCircle this might be s similar reason.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Here's how the results differ: `GaussianFilter` firstly produces a different result on GPU and CPU. Although they visually appear the same, there is a ***1-2 pixel difference around the borders of the circles***. Now I tried both of them with `HoughCircles` on **CPU** and it identified ***3 circles*** (which was accurate, *I had 3 circles in the image*). On trying the same on **GPU**, it identified ***4 circles***, where 1 was inside the actual circle